# How can I export base64 encrypted pdf files from a spreadsheet in R?

Tags: r, base64

I need to export attachments from MS Dynamics CRM. In the database these files are encoded with Base64.

I didnt find some good examples to decode a Base65-encoded PDF.

```
library(base64)

#csv_Import
ImportFile= read.csv("import/dboFilteredAnnotation.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";")  # read csv file 

#select one cell with the base64 content
OneCell= ImportFile[2,2]

#Export the decoded File
DecodePDF = base64::decode(OneCell,"test.pdf")
```

Expectation:
The script should select 1 cell with the base64 encoded pdf and save it as test.pdf

Error:

```
DecodePDF = base64::decode(OneCell,"test.pdf")
Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation for the function and your error, the second argument needs to be an existing file.  Is there already a 'test.pdf' in your working directory?

Comment: Please make this a reproducible example, otherwise it's pretty hard to troubleshoot this.